# Can't get SharePoint fields with Java lib msgraph-sdk-java-dev for drive item with parenthesis in name

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access the fields associated with a file in my Office 365 root directory (https://www.office.com/) named (1).docx The left paren in the URL is causing some troubles when accessing from Java library, where something works fine from Graph Explorer.

With Microsoft Graph Explorer, I can access it by passing the filename as an argument into children like so:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children('(1).docx')
```

From the msgraph-sdk-java-dev, IDriveItemRequestBuilder has a children method that accepts a String argument.

This instead doesn't try to pass it as an argument to children(), but instead appends a slash, following by the name like

```
...drive/root/children/%281%29.doc
```

Actually.. I encoded the ()s. It doesn't work either way.

Is there some way to have IDriveItemRequestBuilder use the other form of accessing children? Or is there another way I should be accessing the item?

Ultimately.... I need to access the fields associated with the item as such:
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children('(1).docx')/listitem/fields

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by subclassing DriveItemRequestBuilder and overriding children(String id)

```
driveItemReqBldr = new DriveItemRequestBuilder(driveItemReqBldr.getRequestUrl(), driveItemReqBldr.getClient(), null) {
    public IDriveItemRequestBuilder children(String id) {
        return new DriveItemRequestBuilder(getRequestUrlWithAdditionalSegment("children") + "('" + id +"')", getClient(), null);
    }
};
```

Not sure if best way, but it worked.